# Using Office 365 as mail server with SSRS 2019 on Server 2019 Azure VM - error message 'Failure sending mail:'

Tags: ssms, ssrs, sql-server-2019

We have a Windows Server 2019 with SSMA 2019 installed. We also use Office 365.

in the mail settings I have smtp.office365.com, and a the username and password for an account that is set up in our Office 365 instance.

Whenever we try and send reports via email we get the error message 'Failure sending mail: One or more errors occurred.'

The config file shows that it is using port 587.

Are there any extra steps which should be used to get this to work with a Azure VM?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you use the built-in "*Send Test Email*" function?

Comment: This would be against the email settings in SSMS rather than SSRS? I didnt know they were linked, however I get the following error when using the Send Test Email option in SSMS 'Message
The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 1 (2021-03-15T11:56:15). Exception Message: Cannot send mails to mail server. (The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not authenticated to send mail. [CWLP265CA0322.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]).'

Comment: **SSMS** is client tool that is used to access **SSRS**, **SSAS**, **SSIS**, and regular **SQL Server** instances, so **SSMS** is related in that sense. I'll have to research your error, but at least you have a little more context now.

Comment: Just making sure, the accounts you're using to send **SSRS** reports from and the one in your **E-mail Settings** have actual **mailboxes** setup in your O365 system?...none of them are just simple **distribution lists** or any other kind of account without a mailbox?

Comment: It definitely gives me more context as the error message is more detailed. The account I am using is a full user account and has a mailbox, Business Standard account.

Comment: Might be relevant, but the Azure VM is not Azure AD joined, not sure if that will make a difference.